# How to prevent Celery Periodic Tasks from executing late?

Tags: python, celery, celerybeat

I have some tasks in Celery that are scheduled with Celery Beat/Crontab like this:

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'task-1': {
        'task': 'tasks.run_task1',
        'schedule': crontab(hour=5, minute=30, day_of_week='mon-fri'),
    },
    'task-2': {
        'task': 'tasks.run_task2',
        'schedule': crontab(hour=12, minute=0, day_of_week='sun-fri'),
    },
}
```

Sometimes I have the Celery process turned off and when I turn it back on at 4:00pm, it will run the tasks from earlier in the day. How can I make it so that these tasks will only run within ~5 minutes of when they are actually scheduled and NOT start to run later in the day?

Answer (score 4):

Use the [expires](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html#expiration) option:

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'task-1': {
        'task': 'tasks.run_task1',
        'schedule': crontab(hour=5, minute=30, day_of_week='mon-fri'),
        'options': {
                    'expires': 5*60,
                    },
    },
    'task-2': {
        'task': 'tasks.run_task2',
        'schedule': crontab(hour=12, minute=0, day_of_week='sun-fri'),
        'options': {
                    'expires': 5*60,
                    },
    },
}
```

Comment: This looks promising. I'll accept this as an answer once I try it out with my code. Thanks!

Comment: It looks like this still sends the task late and then sets an expiration for 5 minutes after the late task. I'd like not to send the task at all if it is > 5 minutes after the expected start time.
```[2015-08-20 09:04:03,883: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task task-1 (tasks.run_task1)

[2015-08-20 09:04:05,967: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: tasks.run_task1[5dbaf0f8-3386-4789-94b6-d3b3eb5fc736] expires:[2015-08-20 09:09:03.884989-07:00]```